# Unable to print a range of results with a space between every 3 results

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I print a range of results with a space between every three results?

When I print something like the following:

```
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(i)
```

Output I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3

4
5
6

7
8
9

10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
for i in range(1, 11):
    print(i)
    if i % 3 == 0:
        print('')
```

Should do it!

Basically, it just checks that `i` is modulo `3`. If it is, it will just print an empty line.

###### Example with a more complex loop

In the case that you have a loop that goes from `a` to `b` and that you want to print an empty line every `c` print, you can do:

```py
for i in range(a, b):
    print(i)
    if (i - a + 1) % c == 0:
        print("")
```